# How to know which XSD element should be defined with a adapter in C++?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd

```
 <xsd:complexType name="Parallel">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="otx:CompoundNode">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="realisation" type="otx:ParallelRealisation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Simplly post an XSD fragment like above, I'm trying to generate it to C++ code, I have to define a class that is used to describe CompoundNode type, but also a class describe Parallel type.
while in fact, the instance of Parallel type would be like this:

```
<CompoundNode xsi:type="Parallel">
```

...

In C++ code, I shold design another class as an adapter to transfer the base class CompoundNode to a specified sub class(Indeed there are many classes derived from CompoundNode in my xsd file), surely you could say that's just polymorphism.

My question: what is the rule in the XSD schema when I don't know which base class should be designed with a adapter class.

Comment: Which code generator do you use? There is an open source code generator [CodeSynthesis XSD](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) that produces C++. They have a polymorphism example: https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/xsd/xsd/tree/examples/cxx/tree/polymorphism

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the link you attached here, I shall have a deep research on it later. Thanks again!